# Using Matlab symbolic toolkit to get the positive root

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Using the Matlab symbolic toolkit, consider a square root formula like the following:

```
syms c;         assume(c,'real');       assumeAlso(c > 0);      
syms d;         assume(d,'real');       assumeAlso(d > 0);      
N = (d^2 + 8*c)^0.5 - d
isAlways(N > 0)
```

Given that c and d are both positive, my intuition was that N should always be positive.
d^2 +  8*c > d^2, so the root should be larger. But then I agreed with Matlab, because the square roots of 100 are actually both +10 and -10, and so sqrt(100) - 9 could be greater or less than 0 (1 or -19). But I can't figure out how to tell Matlab, using the Matlab symbolic toolbox, that I want the positive root of d^2 + 8*c and not the negative one. How do I do that? What commands should I use to tell the symbolic toolkit that I want the positive root?

To clarify the questions below, I would like a generic solution for taking the square root of a positive symbolic Matlab expression and getting the positive root. So if sqrt(a), where 'a' is a mathematical expression of many terms that I know is positive, I want to return the positive root (abs(sqrt(a))).

Comment: Does `N = sqrt(d^2 + 8*c) - d` produce a different result?

Comment: Based on the recent edit, you can just use ```abs``` to make sure the expression is positive… I really don’t understand the problem here.

Comment: When I run the code

    clear;
    syms c;   assume(c,'real');  assumeAlso(c > 0);  
    syms d;   assume(d,'real');  assumeAlso(d > 0);
    N = (d^2 + 8*c)^0.5 - d;
    N2 = abs((d^2 + 8*c)^0.5) - d;
    isAlways(N2==N)

I get that yes, N2 is always equal to N, so that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to use isAlways without assigning the expressions to another variable? Get rid of N and N2 and build the condition you want to check using directly the expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions can be set on symbolic expressions (see [here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.assume.html)), so what about `assume((d^2 + 8*c)^0.5>0)`?

EDIT: as the following command yields "true"

```
isAlways((d^2 + 8*c)^0.5)
```

it is safe to assume that the symbolic engine evaluates the square root of the expression `(d^2 + 8*c)` as positive, therefore considering only the positive root.

Comment: This works in my specific case but doesn't generalize enough for me. The "d^2 + 8*c" part is produced by other analysis and changes. So I don't want to hard code the assumption. Instead, I want a generic solution to the root function if possible.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know *now*. At the time you posted the question you elected to withhold that piece of information. How was I supposed to infer that from the original post? :)

Comment: Also, you’ll have to provide a bit more details about what exactly you are trying to accomplish. There’s no way to tell which of the two roots will end up being positive without actually plugging some numbers in.

Comment: I was hoping it was clear I wanted the positive root from the title of the question which says "Using Matlab symbolic toolkit to get the positive root". You provided an assumption that the root is positive, but there are always 2 roots, and I want to get the positive one as a conclusion.

Comment: It wasn’t clear that you wanted the symbolic expression that would be granted to be the positive root, sorry. Maybe you can edit your question to clarify that detail. As you just phrased it, it’s not possible for the symbolic engine to tell.

Comment: If you want the positive root, you have to plug in some real number!